# Export button disabled in reportviewer in D365

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

In D365, when I run a custom SSRS report, the next/previous page and export buttons are all disabled, despite the report having multiple pages and the need for export to PDF. I do not think we have customized the report viewer code and I can't find any information online about this. Has anybody encountered this and how do I enable these buttons?

[image]

Comment: I noticed it says "Finance and Operations **Preview**" in your screenshots, meaning you are probably using a PEAP version. Can you reproduce this in a GA version? Can you reproduce it with other users or other environments?

Comment: I'm using a dev environment deployed from LCS, we are already live on a GA version. Any nomenclature like "preview" is likely misleading as I made no changes to the environment after deploying a development topology from LCS. Product version 10.0.17 plateform update 41

Comment: @rjv Just run into the same issue, I thought I was the only one. Any findings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that you need to enable Report PDF viewer and related features in Feature management. Looks like they deprecated all export formats of SSRS report viewer.

[image: Report Viewer feature management screenshot]

Comment: I already have the feature enabled, but I will try enable all report viewer features, and disable/reenable etc. to see if that will work.